# How to return an image in Spring Boot controller and serve like a file system

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've tried the various ways given in Stackoverflow, maybe I missed something.

I have an Android client (whose code I can't change) which is currently getting an image like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

Where `url` is the location of the image (static resource on CDN). Now my Spring Boot API endpoint needs to behave like a file resource in the same way so that the same code can get images from the API (Spring boot version 1.3.3).

So I have this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/Image/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("id")String id) {
    byte[] image = imageService.getImage(id);  //this just gets the data from a database
    return ResponseEntity.ok(image);
}
```

Now when the Android code tries to get `http://someurl/image1.jpg` I get this error in my logs:

> Resolving exception from handler [public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   com.myproject.MyController.getImage(java.lang.String)]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation

Same error happens when I plug `http://someurl/image1.jpg` into a browser.

Oddly enough my tests check out ok:

```
Response response = given()
            .pathParam("id", "image1.jpg")
            .when()
            .get("MyController/Image/{id}");

assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatusCode());
byte[] array = response.asByteArray(); //byte array is identical to test image
```

How do I get this to behave like an image being served up in the normal way? (Note I can't change the content-type header that the android code is sending)

**EDIT**

Code after comments (set content type, take out `produces`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Image/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("id")String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    byte[] image = imageService.getImage(id);  //this just gets the data from a database
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(image);
}
```

In a browser this just seems to give a stringified junk (byte to chars i guess). In Android it doesn't error, but the image doesn't show.

Comment: What does the client send as its Accept header? What happens when you remove the produces attribute, and just specify the content type in the response?

Comment: @JBNizet the Accept header is whatever the default is for HttpURLConnection (Android SDK). It's definitely not specifically set. I tried omitting `produces` but that seems to deliver plain text (in a browser). Setting content-type is same as `produces` anyway, no?

Comment: @JBNizet I tried setting the content type explicitly too, I get the same error in the log

Comment: https://youtu.be/Jv7TLWjOz4g

Comment: this well prepared video tutorial step by step guide, to how to read image from spring boot backend,  in hear front end working on Angular.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally fixed this... I had to add a `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` to my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` subclass:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    final ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter arrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
    final List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    arrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(list);
    converters.add(arrayHttpMessageConverter);

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Comment: this answer seems incomplete. Do you have a complete solution that looks like @Roman's answer?

Answer (score 24):

I believe this should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Image/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    byte[] image = imageService.getImage(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(image);
}
```

Notice that the content-type is set for `ResponseEntity`, not for `HttpServletResponse` directly.

Comment: thanks, i did actually try this permutation but it did not work for me

Comment: @user2393012 Strange, because I checked and it works for me. Did you notice I also removed `consumes`, `produces` and `@ResponseBody`? And what error did you get with this code?

Comment: yes, noticed the omissions. I didn't get any error actually, in the browser it just appeared as a empty frame

Comment: @user2393012 Did you check the response headers? Empty frame could be an empty image.

Comment: no but the image from the database hasn't been touched - on Spring side i do output the `byte[]` length and it's fairly sizeable

Comment: @user2393012 There is also a possibility that the request was handled by some other controller method.

Answer (score 8):

In case you don't know the file/mime type you can do this.... I've done this where i take an uploaded file and replace the file name with a guid and no extension and browsers / smart phones are able to load the image no issues. 
 the second is to serve a file to be downloaded.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("img")
public class ImageController {

@GetMapping("showme")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() throws IOException{
    File img = new File("src/main/resources/static/test.jpg");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.valueOf(FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(img))).body(Files.readAllBytes(img.toPath()));
}
@GetMapping("thing")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> what() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/static/thing.pdf");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +file.getName())
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(file)))
            .body(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
}


}
```

*UPDATE* in java 9+ you need to add `compile 'com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0'` to your dependencies this has also been moved or picked up by jakarta.[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493613/what-is-the-replacement-for-javax-activation-package-in-java-9)

Comment: For some files (apple pass/wallet ) to work properly you have to include content length.

Comment: Thank you, `getImage()` method worked for me. But I had a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport` while setting `contentType()`. Finally I just used `contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)` instead of dynamic content type creation and exception is gone. My way works not only for JPEG, but also for PNG.

Comment: i think this is an issue with java 9+. i may take a look at how to keep it dynamic and post an update.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I use Java 10. I hope you'll find a way. :)

Comment: Thank you, I have checked this solution and it really works!

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Commons, you can do this and expose the image on an endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{imageid}",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable int imageid) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(getImage(imageid));
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

All images will be served at endpoint `/image/{imageid}`