# Spring boot doesnt accept file extensions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-extension

I am using `Spring boot v1.5.3.RELEASE` and right now, I can download files normally if I no include the extension file. When I try to download files using the typical file extensions (jpg, jpeg, mp3, mp4, etc), the Spring drops the request. An example request could be: `localhost:8888/public/file/4.jpg`

My **Application.java** is:

```
public class Application extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  System.getProperties().put( "server.port", 8888 );
    //  System.getProperties().put( "spring.thymeleaf.mode", "LEGACYHTML5" );
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
                                 RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
                config.exposeIdsFor(Noticia.class, file.class, Label.class, Reaction.class);
            }
        };

    }



}
```

My **Controller.java** piece of code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "public/file/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getPublicFileWithSuffix(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
        
        
        System.out.println("filename with suffix separated! " + filename);
        String id = filename.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0];
        
        file file = fileRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
        File f = new File("/srv/Ressaca/locals/" + file.getId() + file.getExtension());
    return new FileSystemResource(f); 
}
```

After googling I have found a partial solution. With this solution, if I type some like `localhost:8888/public/file/4.hello` or `localhost:8888/public/file/4.jpj` it works, but if the extension is some real extension like (jpg,jpeg,mp3,mp4 etc) the Spring boot continues dropping the request.

**Controller** after googling:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "public/file/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getPublicFile(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
        
        
        System.out.println("filename " + filename);
        String id = filename.split(Pattern.quote("."))[0];
        
        file file = fileRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
        File f = new File("/srv/Ressaca/locals/" + file.getId() + file.getExtension());
    return new FileSystemResource(f); 

}
```

How can I enable the "real files extension"?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557637/how-to-return-an-image-in-spring-boot-controller-and-serve-like-a-file-system

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to add `consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE`

Comment: For some reason Spring takes the URL file extension into account and overrides the value from the accept header with the implied media type that comes from the extension. (At least that is what I saw debugging this problem Spring 4.3.10.RELEASE.)

For example you have `.../file.txt` then it will try to match `text/plain` even if the accept header is `application/json`.

Solution is to end the URL in the browser with a trainling `/`, like `.../file.txt/`

Answer (score 2):

Try using * instead of + but anything should work. I don't find any restriction sending extension from query parameter in any version of Spring Boot.

```
@RequestMapping("/public/file/{fileName:.*}")
```