# Add Java system modules to compile in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I have some legacy Java code, ie.:

```
package org.alo.test.j9;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   // in java.activation module
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; // in java.xml.ws.annotation module
public class OldClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(null, null);
        System.out.println(dh);
    }
}
```

That is not yet modularized so it requires to use `--add-modules` to compile it with Java 9.

```
$ javac -version
javac 9
$ javac org/alo/test/j9/OldClass.java
src/org/alo/test/j9/OldClass.java:3: error: package javax.activation is not visible
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   // in java.activation module
            ^
  (package javax.activation is declared in module java.activation, which is not in the module graph)
src/org/alo/test/j9/OldClass.java:4: error: package javax.annotation is not visible
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; // in java.xml.ws.annotation module
            ^
  (package javax.annotation is declared in module java.xml.ws.annotation, which is not in the module graph)
2 errors
```

I need to add the modules I'm using in order to be able to successfully compile:

```
$ javac org/test/OldClass.java --add-modules=java.activation,java.xml.ws.annotation
```

I want to compile it in Eclipse (using Oxygen.1a) with Java 9. But I get `The import javax.activation cannot be resolved` compilation error.

How can I tell the eclipse compiler to add these modules? I didn't find any tip in [Eclipse documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java9/Examples) about it.

[Here](https://github.com/alostale/test-j9-eclipse) you can find a simple eclipse project I'm testing with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the replacement for javax.activation package in java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493613/what-is-the-replacement-for-javax-activation-package-in-java-9). The reason of it being Deprecated and Upgradeable.

Comment: @nullpointer That is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: In that case, could you share the Run configurations of Eclipse in use with project settings along with?

Comment: @nullpointer `java.activation` module was just an example of what I needed, I've added another module for the same. Also I included a [link](https://github.com/alostale/test-j9-eclipse) to the testing code I'm using with all Eclipse settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete documentation for these features still needs to be written, but a start has been made in the [New & Noteworthy for Photon M3](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/M3/#java-9) *(work in progress)*. The functionality you are looking for is mentioned in the paragraph starting with

> On the Contents tab individual modules inside a container like JRE System Library can be included or excluded by moving the module from left-to-right or vice versa ...

This dialog tab combines effects of `--add-modules` and `--limit-modules`.

**Edit**: In Eclipse 2019-06 the UI mentioned above has been [revamped](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/jdt.php#buildpath-module-dependencies). Up-to-date documentation can be found in the [online help](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm#module-dependencies).