# Mirth/Java10 - Missing Class to Send Email

Tags: java, mirth, mirth-connect

**Mirth 3.6.0, Java 10**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource

Hello,

I am getting the error above when trying to send an email through Mirth. I have read that a class is missing from Java 10 but I cannot find clear instructions to successfully resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In JDK 9 and JDK 10, the modules that contain CORBA or the APIs
>   shared  between Java SE and Java EE are not resolved by default when
>   you  compile or run code on the class path. These modules are
>   deprecated  for removal. The policy of not resolving these modules is
>   a first step  toward removing these APIs from Java SE and the JDK in a
>   future  release. The deprecated modules are:
>
> - java.corba — CORBA
> - java.transaction — The subset of the Java
>     Transaction API defined by  Java SE to support CORBA Object Transaction Services
> - java.activation — JavaBeans Activation Framework
> - java.xml.bind — Java Architecture  for XML Binding (JAXB)
> - java.xml.ws — Java API for XML Web Services  (JAX-WS), Web Services Metadata for the Java Platform, and SOAP with  Attachments for Java (SAAJ)
> - java.xml.ws.annotation — The subset of  the JSR-250 Common Annotations defined by Java SE to support web  services
>
> Existing code with references to classes in these APIs will not
>   compile without changes to the build. Similarly, code on the class
>   path with references to classes in these APIs will fail with
>   NoDefClassFoundError or ClassNotFoundException unless changes are made
>   in how the application is deployed.
>
> See [JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320) to get more information about migration options, possible replacements for the modules, and to track the
>   progress of the removal of the Java EE and CORBA modules from the JDK.

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/migrate/JSMIG.pdf)

You have two option:

- As Oracle migration guide proposes to use `--add-modules java.activation` option during JVM start. You can set this in `mirth.properties` for Mirth Connect

**or**

- add [JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493613/what-is-the-replacement-for-javax-activation-package-in-java-9) to your dependencies. In Mirth Connect you would add this JAR to a Resource Directory and make your Channel depend on that resource