# How do I go about Deploying a channel with a connector type of HTTP Sender as a destiantion in Mirth?

Tags: java, macos, mirth, mirth-connect

I have created a channel with a destiantion of HTTP Sender type in Mirth connect but I cant get the channel to deploy. If fails with a message:

```
ERROR  (com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ErrorTaskHandler:25): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
```

I have installed Mirth 3.6.1 running on Java 10 in a Mac OS.

There is a solution that might help me and has been suggested but I am so new to Mirth that I do not understand how to implement it.

[Suggested Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166659/mirth-java10-missing-class-to-send-email/53761069?noredirect=1#comment94373960_53761069)

Answer (score 0):

From page 22 of the 3.6 user guide:

**Using Java 9 or greater**

Currently as per the System Requirements, Mirth Connect version 3.6 supports Java 8 at minimum, and also supports Java 9 and 10. In order to use Java 9 or greater, you'll first need to perform an extra manual step.

In the Installation Directory, there should be a **docs** folder. Inside, there is a file called **mcservice-java9+.vmoptions**. This contains some extra JVM options that allow Mirth Connect to run with Java 9 or greater without errors or warnings.

Copy the contents into either the **mcserver.vmoptions** or **mcservice.vmoptions** file, depending on whether your
deployment uses mcserver or mcservice. Then restart Mirth Connect. If you're using Java 9 or greater for the
client-side Administrator GUI, make sure also to clear your Java cache and re-launch from the launch page:
Launching the Mirth Connect Administrator

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work. I simply downgraded to java 8 to proceed.