# How to Run XJC in Java 9+

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, java-11

I downloaded [JAXB 2.3.0.1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.0.1) and [JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) 1.2.0](https://github.com/javaee/activation/releases) (based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493809/960115)).  I extracted all JAR files to the same directory, then run the following command within that directory:

```
java -cp jaxb-api.jar;jaxb-core.jar;jaxb-impl.jar;javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
    -jar jaxb-xjc.jar [xjc-arguments]
```

The above command fails with the following message:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
>       ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource

I have verified that class exists within the javax.activation-1.2.0.jar file.  I have also tried using the new (to Java 9+) arguments `-p . --add-modules java.activation`, but that fails with the following error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.modules.ResolutionException: Modules jaxb.core and jaxb.impl export package com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller to module java.activation

If I try a combination of `-cp` and `--add-modules`, I get a different boot layer initialization error.  Does anyone know how to get XJC to run using a Java 9+ platform?

My specific use case is OpenJDK 11 on Windows.

Comment: Try [downloading the version](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:javax.activation%20g:com.sun.activation) they've asked people to migrate to - `a:javax.activation g:com.sun.activation` and make sure to reference the correct jar names. Since the `DataSource` class in the logs seems to be [right there](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/blob/master/activation/src/main/java/javax/activation/DataSource.java) in the artifact.

Comment: You can't specify both -cp and -jar at the same time, I assume you mean to put jaxb-xjc.jar on the class path and specify its main class instead.

Comment: @nullpointer I downloaded the version you linked, but it is binary identical to the version I was already using (verified via cryptographic hash).

Comment: Upgrade to `jaxb-api` version 2.3.1, then you don't have to explicitly include JAF anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue was that the *java* executable doesn't support specifying both the `-cp` and `-jar` command-line arguments at the same time.  Thanks to Alan Bateman for that information!

Therefore, the correct way to get this to work is by using the following command:

```
java -cp javax.activation-1.2.0.jar;jaxb-xjc.jar com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade
    [xjc-arguments]
```

In order to simplify running XJC, open *bin/xjc.bat* (extracted from jaxb-ri-2.3.0.zip), and edit the command line to match the above call.