# Several java 'activation' libraries define overlapping classes. Which one to use?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am using the latest stable version of quite standard Java libraries such as Spring, yet getting 'overlapping classes' warning from maven shade plugin about three different libraries that define the same classes.

The libraries: `jakarta.activation-api`, `javax.activation-api`, `activation`.

Specifically:

1. `jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2` (dependency of `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3`)
2. `javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0` (dependency of `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1`, I think this one should be replaced by `jakarta.xml.bind-api`, but not sure)
3. `javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1` (dependency of `com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2`)

**What library is the 'right' one that will cause the least amount of trouble?**

**Update**: it seems that `jakarta.xml.bind-api` replaces `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` (proof: [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/issues/18) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/pull/692)), so in the conflict between (1) and (2) the jakarta one (`jakarta.activation-api`) should be preferred over the javax one (`javax.activation-api`). The preferred JAXB dependencies are described [in Jakarta web site](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/). But it is still unclear how is this related to `javax.activation:activation`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got it.
JavaBeans activation framework has been moved to Jakarta Activation, see [Jakarta JAF page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaf/), it means `javax.activation:activation` is out of date.
The right one seems to be [jakarta activation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation), thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493853/1847482).

Same for emails and XML processing that require the activation JAR - use the Jakarta ones: `com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail` and `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api`.