# Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/ws/WebServiceException

Tags: java

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2f6791f5
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/ws/WebServiceException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.getFICodec(SOAPBindingCodec.java:491)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.<init>(SOAPBindingCodec.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.<init>(SOAPBindingCodec.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Codecs.createSOAPBindingCodec(Codecs.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageContextFactory.<init>(MessageContextFactory.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageContextFactory.<init>(MessageContextFactory.java:82)
    at com.oracle.webservices.api.message.MessageContextFactory.<clinit>(MessageContextFactory.java:57)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:882)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:899)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:451)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:402)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:169)
```

I'm trying to run my Batch application  during this I want to connect to another application via some property file.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that you have no `jakarta/xml/ws/WebServiceException` class definition in Java Runtime.

Still, you managed to compile this, which means either this class is not needed during the compilation process (for instance loaded through `Class.forName`) or it is marked as compile time only. I do not know what build tool you are using, but it seems you need to put declare dependency like this for Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or like this for Gradle

```
compile group: 'jakarta.xml.ws', name: 'jakarta.xml.ws-api', version: '3.0.1'
```

P.S: I have noticed the `jakarta` package, I'm guessing you are in the process of transitioning from `javax` to `jakarta`, if so, you may find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159654/migrate-from-javax-to-jakarta-ee) useful.

Comment: After adding jakarta.xml.ws dependency it worked for me.

Comment: Then please mark the answer as accepted to complete this issue